# Soundpool SetMaxStreams method seems not to work

Tags: java, android, media, soundpool

My project is a simple app which reproduces sounds by tapping a button in a ListView. Everything works fine except that method.

This is the class "Effetti" :

```
.
.
.
public Effetti(Context context, int resId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
Builder21(); 
} 

else    
{
createSoundPoolWithConstructor();
}

  am =  (AudioManager)  
   context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);                  
    volume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   soundID = sound.load(context, resId, PRIORITY);     
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

protected void Builder21(){

AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
.build();
 sound = new SoundPool.Builder().setAudioAttributes(attributes).setMaxStreams(1).build();

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

protected void createSoundPoolWithConstructor(){
  sound = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
 }


 public void playsound() { 

  sound.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);   

  }
```

In this way,the constructor should works with all the API target.I'm using API 21 .

In the .Wash class i create an array with the objects i need using the inner class AsyncTask . in the onResume() method i execute the task and in the onPause() method i can release all the resources.

I'm using a ListView and the onItemClick method. There is a known limit of 32 sounds in the SoundPool so i decided to release each sound after been playing and to recreate it. I do this using Threads.Maybe is not so clean but for now it works and also the UI works fine.

```
.
.
.
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterv, final View componente, int pos, long id){          

    switch(pos){case 0: 

    sound_one.playsound(); 

    new Thread (new Runnable(){ 
          @Override
            public void run(){
               try {Thread.sleep(50000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                 sound_one.release();sound_one=new Effetti(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.boom);
               }
             }).start();
    } 
    switch(pos){case 1:

        sound_two.playsound(); 

        new Thread (new Runnable(){ 
      @Override
        public void run(){    
           try {Thread.sleep(50000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
             sound_two.release();sound_two=new Effetti(getBaseContext(),R.raw.exp);
           }
         }).start();
```

My problem is that the sounds can be played at the same time,and i really don't want it to happen! i've setted the MaxStreams method to 1 but it won't work. 
Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: *Upgrade: the method works but inside each single click only. If i play a sound and at the same time i press again the same button,the sound stops and start again. So the maxstreams seems to work in this case. I don't know how to let it works in the other cases..when a button is pressed the sound will start,and if i press another button,another sound starts at the same time. I actually don't know how to modify the constructor